# Find ViewController in NavigationController with special key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a NavigationController with different ViewControllers. Sometimes I want to push a ViewController to NavigationController, which is already included.
In this case I want to move to the existing from TopController, and pop all other ViewControllers between top and the existing one.

Is there a way to give a ViewController a special id (for example a NSString), to find him later in "NavigationController.viewControllers"?
Or should I use a seperate Dictionary to manage my ViewControllers?

Or is there a better way, I dont consider.

best regards

Comment: Are some of the view controllers the same class, or are they all different?

Comment: Most times the same class, but different contents. But I have a unique ID for every content.

Answer (score 4):

On your appDelegate, you can store all your ViewController and when you want to pop call :

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Or you can try to search

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers 
for (UIVIewController *anVC in viewControllers) {
    if (anVC isKindOfClass:[yourController class] {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:anVC animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The view controllers are the same class, most times.

Comment: Ok, so add a custom property like a tag or id, and if(anVC.tag == lookingTag) it's the good one. Or use the first method with view controllers storage.

Answer (score 1):

### Note : As the view controllers are the same class, most times

#### Add strUniqueID property on each controller while pushing view controller to navigation controller don't forget to set it

Now you know which unique ID's you want remove, so find it

```
//Firstly find your viewController
for(id viewcontroller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
     //For finding specific viewController use isKindOfClass
     if(viewcontroller isKindOfClass:[YourViewControllerNameHere Class])
     {
         //Now find UniqueIDHere
         YourViewController *objYourViewController = (YourViewController *)viewcontroller
         if(YourViewControllerNameHere.strUniqueID isEqualToString:removeUniqueIDHere])
         {
             //Now pop to YourViewController
             [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
             break;
         }
         
     }
     else if(viewcontroller isKindOfClass:[YourDifferentViewControllerNameHere Class]) //Different ViewControllers here like this
     {
         //Now find UniqueIDHere
         YourDifferentViewController *objYourDifferentViewController = (YourViewController *)viewcontroller
         if(YourDifferentViewController.strUniqueID isEqualToString:removeUniqueIDHere])
         {
             //Now pop to YourViewController
             [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
             break;
         }
     }
       
}
```

---

Try this :

```
//Firstly find your viewController
for(id viewcontroller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
     //For finding specific viewController use isKindOfClass
     if(viewcontroller isKindOfClass:[YourViewControllerNameHere Class])
     {
         //Now pop to YourViewController
         [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: The view controllers are the same class, most times.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```swift
let vc = navVC.viewControllers.first(where: { $0.hasKey })
```