# Swift 4.2 Delegate and Protocol no working

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIViewController`(`profileViewController`) in which there is `collectionView`, the `collectionView` have `headerCell` in which there is `segmentedControl`, when the `segmentedControl` value change, i want to tiger the `delegate` method but it not working, here is the code,
this is the class of `collectioview headercell`, and protocol.

```
import UIKit

// Protocol

protocol headerCellSegmentedDelegate {
    func changeTabe(whichOne : String)
}

// HeaderCell Class

class HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
    var  headerDelegate : headerCellSegmentedDelegate?
    @IBAction func changeValue(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            headerDelegate?.changeTabe(whichOne: "0")
        }else{
             headerDelegate?.changeTabe(whichOne: "1")
        }
    }
  }
```

In the same `UIViewController`(`profileViewController`) which have the `collectionView`

```
    // profileViewController 
import UIKit
import SideMenu

class profileViewController: UIViewController {

    //let headdercell = HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView()
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // headdercell.headerDelegate = self //still not working with this too
        setupSideMenu()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
extension profileViewController : headerCellSegmentedDelegate {
    func changeTabe(whichOne: String) {
        print("which tab " + whichOne)
    }
}
```

i Try with protocol with class and weak, but still not working.

Comment: where did you defined the delegate in the ViewController.

Comment: can you please again review the code?
i extend the ViewController with protocol its delegate method,
extension profileViewController : headerCellSegmentedDelegate {
    func changeTabe(whichOne: String) {
        print("which tab " + whichOne)
    }
}

Comment: don't write your code in comment, use `edit` option and update your code.

Comment: i have updated the code above

Comment: You need to confirm your headerDelegate refrences of your class (profileViewController).

Comment: updated the code : still not working

Comment: let headdercell = HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView()

You add above line that means you create new refrences of HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView, Please not initialized  new variable .

try to get HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView refrences from navigation controller.

Comment: how to get refrences from navigation controller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407380/find-viewcontroller-in-navigationcontroller-with-special-key . refer it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code

```
//let headdercell = HeaderProfileCollectionReusableView()
```

shouldn't be commented.

Second, after you uncomment that, assign headerDelegate value to self.

```
headdercell.headerDelegate = self
```